# bulk insert works in ssms but not in other applications

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Context: SQL Server 2005

I have a simple proc, which does a bulk load from an external file.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_test] 
AS 
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#promo') is not null BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #promo
   END

   CREATE TABLE #promo (promo VARCHAR(1000))

   BULK INSERT #promo
   FROM '\\server\c$\file.txt'
   WITH
   (
      --FIELDTERMINATOR = '',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
   )

   select * from #promo
```

I can run it in SSMS. But when I call it from another application (Reporting service 2005), it throws this error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\server\c$\file.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.).

Here is complicated because it may related to the account used by reporting service, or some windows security issue.

But I think I can maybe impersonate the login as the one I used to create the proc because the login can run it in SSMS. So tried to change the proc to 'with execute as self', it compiles ok, but when I tried to run it in SSMS, I got:

> Msg 4834, Level 16, State 4, Procedure usp_test, Line 12
>   You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.

I am still in the same session, so when I run this, it actually execute as the 'self', which is the login I am using now, so why I got this error? What should I do?

I know it's bit unclear so just list the facts.

========update

I just tried using SSIS to load the file into a table so that the report can use. The package runs ok in BIDS but when runs in sql agent job it  got the same access to the file is denied error. Then I set up a proxy and let the package run under that account and the job runs no problem.

So I am thinking is it the account ssrs used can't access the file? What account is used by ssrs? Can ssrs be set up to run under a proxy like sql agent does?

==============update again
Finally got it sorted

I have created a SSIS package, put the package in a job (running under a proxy account to access the file), and in the proc to execute the job. This does work although tricky (need to judge whether the job has finished in the proc). This is too tricky to maintain, so just create as a proof of concept, will not go into production.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/761b3c62-c636-407d-99b5-5928e42f3cd8/execute-as-problem?forum=transactsql

Comment: My friend there has to be a better way to accomplish what you are attempting to accomplish without pulling from a flat file every single time you wish to run a report...

Comment: The problem sounds like it is not the `SQL Server User login` that is used to execute procedure, but `Windows Account` that is SQL Server is trying to use to access the file on the server.

Comment: @Zane there is a parameter (multi selection) on the report, it will be 20 - 50 values out of several hundred values. So users will not pick these values from the huge list. Instead, they can input the values in a file and put it somewhere, then if they choose to use the vales from  file, the report will bulk load the file to do the work. I am sure there are other ways to do it, but now it seems a convenient option.

Answer (score 2):

1) The reason you get the "You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement." is because (naturally) you don't have permissions to use the bulk load statement.

You must either be a **sysadmin** or a **bulkadmin** at the server level to run BULK commands.

2) Yes, "Access is denied" usually means whatever credentials you are using to run the sproc in SSRS does not have permissions to that file. So either:

- Make the file available to everyone.
- Set a known credential with full access to the file to the datasource running the sproc.

3) What the heck, dude.

- Why not just use the text file directly as a data source in SSRS?
- If that's not possible, why not perform all your ETL in one sproc run outside SSRS, and then just use a simple "select * from table" statement for SSRS?
- Please do not run a BULK INSERT **every time someone wants the report**. If they need up to date reads of the file, use the file as a data source. If they can accept, say, a 10 minute lag in data, create a batch job or ETL process to pick the file up and put it into a database table every 10 minutes and just read from that. **Write once, read many.**

Comment: Part 3 = +1 there is no reason to do ETL every single time someone loads a report it seems very very silly.

Comment: @kyle Why not just use the text file directly as a data source in SSRS? I don't see a option in SSRS 2005 data source that can use a file as a data source? Is this something new in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: yes, I know it's not a good practice to do this 'dirty stuff' in reporting, but this report is quite ad hoc and users can use different values each time so that's how I came up with this.

Comment: @kyle regarding 1). I have already set the login to server role sysadmin and bulkadmin. But when I run the proc (with execute as the login), it still tell me 'You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.'

Comment: @thotwielder Create an ODBC data source using the Microsoft Text Driver pointing to your file and use that as your data source in SSRS.

Comment: Also, EXECUTE AS SELF is a static call to the execution_principal_id in sys.sql_modules, which may not be you, and may not be a sysadmin/bulkadmin. It's probably whoever owns the dbo schema on your database, but that's not 100% the case.

Comment: @kyle thanks for the reply. Updated in the original question.